# What is the name for this operator, and how can it be applied to multiple variables within the same equation?

Tags: notation

My question is in two parts; the first is, what is the $|$ operator called? Here's an example of it in use:

$$(x + 5)|_{x=3} = 8$$

My second question is, how do I use this operator for more than one variable? For example, would I write $(x + y)|_{x=3,y=3}$? Or $(x + y)|_{x=3}|_{y=3}$? Or another variation?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $\mid$ usually reads as "such that" or "given that".

In your example, it works pretty clearly: Take $(x+5)$, given that $x=3$. Then $3+5 = 8$.

As another example, $A = \{x \mid x^2 = 4\}$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x^2 = 4$.

So to respond to your second question, you would write $(x+y)|_{x=3,y=3}$. (Given the informal definition I wrote above, the second variation wouldn't make a whole lot of sense.)

Comment: It never occurred to me that those two $\vert$s might be the same $\vert$.